# What is the difference between content-language and accept-language headers in Outlook? How/when are these added?

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-2010, smtp-headers

Outlook 2010 | Windows 7

Can someone please elaborate on the difference between the **content-language** and **accept-language** email headers?

When do these get added by Outlook 2010 and where can I configured these values?

Here's an example:

```
From: Mike <mike@foo.com>
To: Bob <bob@foo2.com>
Date: Tue, 9 Oct 2012 11:25:30 -0700
Subject: Test Message
Thread-Topic: Test Message
Thread-Index: Ac2mSsdlkfjsdlkfjlsdfsd4k04YqkZA==
Message-ID: <B870629719727B4BA82A6C0DLSKJFLSKDJFLSDKJFLSKDFJ2@mailserver.foo.com>
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach: 
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
```

I'm aware that for HTTP, **Content-Language** is from the server, and lets the client know what language(s) are present on the requested page. Accept-Language is from the client, and lets the server know the user's preferred language(s). Is this the same for email?

I have a use case where I'd like a downstream content-filter to key off the language header and perform an action if a certain language is present.

I'm guessing that these are set in the **Outlook Options >> Language** section but would like confirmation.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, these are not properly standardized for email, and only used (or more like abused) by Microsoft.  To add insult to injury, it appears that Exchange sets `Accept-Language:` based on the server's settings, and does not offer a per-user override.